# Drools rule for spikes in heart rate

Tags: java, drools, rule-engine, complex-event-processing, drools-fusion

I only recently started with drools and I need to process heart rate data. I need to create a a rule in drools fusion that fires when there are 3 or more spikes in the heart rate data of 60 or more then the average over the last hour. The picture below is an example what I like to discover in the heart rate.

[image]

My HeartRate events have the following fields:

```
int heartRate;
Date timeStamp;
String macAddress;
```

I know about the the sliding time window but you can only use basic functions like min, max, avg,... . Could someone explain me how I can create this rule?

Comment: Define "spike". It's not a single event exceeding avg+60 (see the first spike). How long must a run of high rate values be to cease being a spike? Note that if you count single events three would be exceeded at 00:28 in your diagram.

Comment: @laune yes you're right. The definition for spike would be: a time window of 1 minute where one or more events exceed avg+60. After this spike the heart rate needs to decrease again to the avg before a new spike can be detected.

Answer (score 1):

Write rules that detect a spike and insert and update a Spike fact, with the properties:

```
declare Spike
  @role( event )
  int maxHeartRate;   ## max/avg rate from events of this spike  
  Date startTS;       ## from first HeartRate to exceed avg+60
  Date lastTS;        ## from last HeartRate to exceed avg+60
  String macAddress;
end
```

Using two accumulates you can correlate the count of Spikes within one hour to the HeartRate's heartRate average of one hour.

Note that there is a (subtle) "fuzziness" to the whole strategy because the average before the first spike is almost certainly lower than the average before the second or third spike as this includes the spikes' rates. Ideally, one would omit these from the average calculation.

I think that it would be easier to avoid window:time and calculate everything from time stamps, possibly even maintain the running average "by hand". But investigating this by writing all of the code, including the test cases, is more than I want to spend here.